# Text data sources in German, primarily news articles

Tags: language, corpora

Can anyone recommend good sources for getting archived news texts in German language?

Good source would satisfy the following conditions:

- recent in date (for example 2005-2015)
- variety of topics (politics ,sport, fashion, lifestyle, food...)
- easy availability (free for download)
- clean (it's easy to separate articles)
- more than 50k articles

Of course, not all of the conditions must be fully satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

We release large corpora of German news for the annual machine translation shared task organised by the WMT conference. Unfortunately it is shuffled (so you cannot reconstruct the original articles) for the reasons given above. The latest release is here: http://www.statmt.org/wmt16/translation-task.html

For 2014, we did actually release a crawl from the Project Syndicate website, with document boundaries. This should (afaik) include German articles http://www.statmt.org/wmt14/news-commentary-v9-by-document.tgz

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, such kind of texts are typically copyrighted and not Open Data.

Some German newspapers, e.g. Frankfurter Rundschau (FR) or die tageszeitung (taz), offer complete volumes on CD for a reasonable price (just visit their sites).

If you can go away with sentences taken out of context (it is impossible to reconstruct the full articles) you can go to the Wortschatz Corpora page of Leipzig University at http://corpora2.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/download.html